# Sending a PNG using HTTP in C#

Tags: c#, http, webserver, png

I'm developing my own simple webserver in C#, and I have normal html files and subfolders etc in place and working fine... however my issue lies with sending PNG files.

Once the browser has made the HTTP request and my other code has done its magic, I need to send a response header. Here is my code to do this:

```
        else if (URL.EndsWith(".ico") || URL.EndsWith(".png"))
        {
            if (File.Exists(Program.Start_Directory + URL))
            {
                byte[] ImgFile = File.ReadAllBytes(Program.Start_Directory + URL);
                sw.Write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
                sw.Write("Content-Type: image/png\r\n");
                sw.Write("Content-Length: " + ImgFile.Length + "\r\n");
                sw.Write("\r\n");
                sw.Write(ImgFile);
            }
            else
            {
                FileNotFoundPage(sw);
            }
        }
```

sw in this instance being the StreamWriter for the socket connection to the browser.

When I run this, the browser screen goes black like it usually does when its about to load an image, but no image loads and the spinning loading wheel remains spinny indefinitely.

How can I get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: You need to protect yourself against [directory traversal attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal). URL might be `../../something` and your app would just let 'em in.

Comment: @spender Been there, done that ;) already implemented elsewhere during the main request handler code which comes before the code shown above.

Comment: So which overload of [`StreamWriter.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write(v=vs.110).aspx) do you believe you are using? ;) I don't see one for `byte[]`, so it's probably the one that takes an object. Might be better to flush the StreamWriter and then write the bytes directly to the underlying stream.

Comment: @spender If you mean that in the way I think you do, there are objects and threads so there will only ever be one sw in that code. This is a multi-threaded webserver.

Comment: No, I'm trying to tell you that there is no `StreamWriter.Write` method that accepts `byte[]`... But the one that takes `object` might be fooling you. Read the manual for it... "Writes the text representation of an object to the text string or stream by calling the ToString method on that object.". So you are writing the bytes for the text value of `ImgFile.ToString()`. That's what StreamWriter does. It writes ***strings*** not *`byte[]`*

Comment: If you want to write an array of bytes, write it directly to the underlying stream.

Comment: Making sure you flush the StreamWriter beforehand.

Comment: Could you post how I do that as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things get messy when you use a `StreamWriter` (which is designed to write strings with a specific `Encoding` to a stream) with binary data.

It looks like you are invoking [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfc2b8zk(v=vs.110).aspx) overload of `StreamWriter.Write` with the belief that it writes the bytes verbatim to the output stream. The docs state that this overload actually...

> Writes the text representation of an object to the text string or stream by calling the ToString method on that object

You have two options. Carry on using `StreamWriter` and `Flush`, then write the binary data directly to the underlying stream:

```
byte[] ImgFile = File.ReadAllBytes(Program.Start_Directory + URL);
sw.Write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
//...etc
sw.Flush();
sw.BaseStream.Write(ImgFile,0,ImgFile.Length);
```

or just do everything in bytes:

```
var sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
//...etc
var headerBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
Stream str = iGotTheStreamFromSomewhere;
str.Write(headerBytes,0,headerBytes.Length);
str.Write(ImgFile,0,ImgFile.Length);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. I upvoted but less than 15 reputation so doesn't count yet, and someone else downvoted.

Comment: Why exactly the Flush()?

Comment: @KreuterCode It's been a long time, but IIRC, StreamWriter can buffer written data (under the assumption that when the StreamWriter is closed/disposed, whatever is buffered will be flushed). If we reach into the underlying stream before eveything is closed and write directly to it, we need to be sure that whatever was written the the StreamWriter has actually been written to the underyling stream before writing directly onto the underlying stream. Hence `StreamWriter.Flush`.